# Drawing flying/moving line on Cesium?

Tags: cesium

How can I draw a flying/moving line on Cesium?

I need a base line and a little point flying from one origin coordinates to a destination, and it needs to be animated.

Cesium only provide basic apis like drawing a line on the surface or towards a certain xyz point.

Comment: Are you asking for something like an airplane's history line, that grows over time as the plane flies around?  Please improve your question by adding additional detail, steps you've tried so far, sample code, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking for something like an airplane's history line, that grows over time as the plane flies around, like this:

[image]

you can enable this by editing the entity's `path` properties, [leadTime](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/PathGraphics.html#leadTime) and [trailTime](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/PathGraphics.html#trailTime).  These are expressed in seconds (of time on Cesium's clock, not realtime).

In this example, I've taken the Cesium [Interpolation Demo](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Interpolation.html) and added two lines to the top of the `path` definition block, such that it looks like this:

```
path : {
    leadTime: 0,
    trailTime: 3 * 60,  // 3 minutes, in seconds of simulation time
    // ... the rest is unchanged.
```

This turns off the path in front of the aircraft, and requests 180 second's worth of the aircraft flight as a trail.

Here's the [final result](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/#c=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) with the modified path.