# Drawing 3D flight path in Cesium?

Tags: cesium

I've been trying to draw 3D flight path in Cesium without any success. I followed the answer from [Drawing flying/moving line on Cesium?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300511/drawing-flying-moving-line-on-cesium)

However, this only renders a segment of flight path floating in the air. What I am trying to do is to render the flight path segment that can be projected/extruded to the ground as in the image below. I looked at the Cesium API document for PathGraphic options https://cesiumjs.org/refdoc/. This API only has leadTime and trailTime.

Does anyone know how Cesium can render a flight path like this?

[image: 3D Flight Path]

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a Sandcastle link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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)

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");

var FEET_TO_METER = 0.3048;
var NAUTICAL_TO_METER = 1852;

var startPointLongitude = -79.66369444444445;
var startPointLatitude = 43.674416666666666;
var startPointAltitude = 618;
var gradient = 3;
var magneticDirection = -10;
var course = 57;
var distance = 7.3;

var startPosition = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(startPointLongitude, startPointLatitude, startPointAltitude * FEET_TO_METER);
var endPosition = calcApproachPathEndPosition(startPosition, gradient, magneticDirection, course, distance);

var pathPositions = [];

pathPositions.push(startPosition);

var positions = new Cesium.CallbackProperty(function () {
                        return pathPositions;
                    }, false);

var fixedFrameTransform = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame;
var heading = courseToCesiumHeading(course, magneticDirection);
var pitch = slopeToCesiumPitch(gradient);
var hpr = new Cesium.HeadingPitchRoll(heading, pitch, 0);

var planePrimitive = viewer.scene.primitives.add(Cesium.Model.fromGltf({
                      url :  "../SampleData/models/CesiumAir/Cesium_Air.glb",
                      modelMatrix : Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollToFixedFrame(startPosition, hpr, Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84, fixedFrameTransform),
                      minimumPixelSize : 64
                  }));

var approachPathEntity = viewer.entities.add({
                    polyline : {
                        positions: positions,
                        material : Cesium.Color.RED,
                        width : 3,
                        arcType : Cesium.ArcType.NONE,
                    }
                });

var wall = viewer.entities.add({
                    wall : {
                        positions: new Cesium.CallbackProperty(function () {
                            return pathPositions;
                        }, false),
                        material : Cesium.Color.GREEN.withAlpha(0.3)
                    }
                });


var currentPosition = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
var speedVector = new Cesium.Cartesian3();
var SPEED = 10;

viewer.scene.preUpdate.addEventListener(function(scene, time) {
    var newPlanePrimitivePosition = new Cesium.Cartesian3();

    currentPosition = Cesium.Matrix4.getTranslation(planePrimitive.modelMatrix, currentPosition);
    var distance = Cesium.Cartesian3.distance(startPosition, currentPosition);

    if( distance > distance)
    {
        // we need to restart simulation
        planePrimitive.modelMatrix = Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollToFixedFrame(startPosition, hpr, Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84, fixedFrameTransform);

        pathPositions.splice(0, pathPositions.length);
        pathPositions.push(startPosition);
    }

    speedVector = Cesium.Cartesian3.multiplyByScalar(Cesium.Cartesian3.UNIT_X, SPEED, speedVector);

    newPlanePrimitivePosition = Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByPoint(planePrimitive.modelMatrix, speedVector, newPlanePrimitivePosition);

    pathPositions.push(newPlanePrimitivePosition);

    Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollToFixedFrame(newPlanePrimitivePosition, hpr, Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84, fixedFrameTransform, planePrimitive.modelMatrix);
});

viewer.camera.flyToBoundingSphere(new Cesium.BoundingSphere(startPosition, 5000));

function slopeToCesiumPitch(slope) {
    var pitch;

    if(slope >= 0)
        pitch = slope;
    else
        pitch = 360 + slope;

    return Cesium.Math.toRadians(pitch);
}

function courseToCesiumHeading(course, magneticDirection) {
    magneticDirection = Number(magneticDirection);

    /*
    * magnetic direction or magnetic variation
    * if west, negative
    * if east, positive
    * */

    // why + 90
    // in this app, x axis points in the east.
    // meanwhile course is measured from north direction.

    var heading = course + magneticDirection + 90;

    return Cesium.Math.toRadians(heading);
}

function calcApproachPathEndPosition(startPosition, gradient, magneticDirection, course, distance) {
    var heading = courseToCesiumHeading(course, magneticDirection);

    var pitch = slopeToCesiumPitch(gradient);

    var hpr = new Cesium.HeadingPitchRoll(heading, pitch , 0);

    var orientation = Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollQuaternion(startPosition, hpr);

    var matrix3Scratch = new Cesium.Matrix3();

    var result = new Cesium.Matrix4();

    result = Cesium.Matrix4.fromRotationTranslation(Cesium.Matrix3.fromQuaternion(orientation, matrix3Scratch), startPosition, result);

    distance = distance * NAUTICAL_TO_METER;

    var endPosition = new Cesium.Cartesian3(distance, 0, 0);

    endPosition = Cesium.Matrix4.multiplyByPoint(result, endPosition, new Cesium.Cartesian3());

    return endPosition;
}
```

Comment: I followed your Sandcastle link, and it worked perfectly. So, thank you. Then, I studied your code and looked it over and over. But I could not understand this statement: if( distance > distance). How can a variable greater than itself?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It was my mistake.
The original purpose of it was to restart flying based on flying distance like this.

 if( distance > 1000)


the distance variable indicates flying distance.